# how to convert .mat file into bitmap in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert a .mat file into a bitmap image in Matlab but I cannot seem to find a way to do it. This is my current code:

```
 human_seg = load(human_img);
```

where the human_img is a .mat file. I need to then convert the human_seg into a bmp but when I try it I recieve the error

```
Conversion to logical from struct is not possible.
```

Comment: how are you trying to change `human_seg` into bmp?

Comment: i tried doing bmp = logical(human_seg), but that returned the error above

Comment: There is probably a field in the structure `human_seg` that has the matrix data in it.  So you will have to access that field instead.  In the Command Window, just type `human_seg` and observe the result to get the field name.  Then convert to the black and white image as `img=logical(human_seg.myField)`.

Comment: Type in `human_seg` into the command prompt and show us what MATLAB gives you.  As Geoff said, this is probably a structure with multiple fields.  There may be a field in the structure that contains your image data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
imwrite(human_seg,'Imagefile1.bmp')
```